Replacing channel based graceful shutdown with Context and errgroup based solution
For quite some time, I have been using the following code in my http server application to initiate a graceful shutdown. Stripped off unnecessary codes that aren't contributing right now.
shutdownChan := make(chan error)

go func() {
    quitChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(quitChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-quitChan

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10 * time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    shutdownChan <- srv.Shutdown(ctx)
}()

err := srv.ListenAndServe()

err = <-shutdownChan


To make sure I know what I am doing here, I will rubber duck a bit.
First, shutdownChan is used to receive errors that might occur during the shutdown process inside the goroutine.
Inside the go func() function, first we need a way to hold the execution of the goroutine so that it doesn't exit. We declare a channel for receiving signal, and the <-quitChan line keeps waiting for the signal and blocks the execution.
When a signal is passed, eg. Ctrl+C is pressed, execution moves to the next line. We create a context which will get a timeout after 10 seconds and call the cancel() function, aka stop all works and release the resources. Then we call the srv.Shutdown(ctx) function, return any error to the main goroutine through the previously created shutdownChan channel.
I hope all clear so far (kindly point out if I have any misunderstanding about any concept). Now I want to do two things.

Use signal.NotifyContext in place of signal.Notify.
Use errgroup to return errors from the goroutine instead of using a channel.

What I figured so far about the new code is:
ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
defer stop()

g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

g.Go(func() error {
    <-ctx.Done()
    
    shutdownCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10 * time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    return srv.Shutdown(shutdownCtx)
})

err := g.Wait()

I won't explain the details what I am doing here since it's intended to achieve the same thing as before in same concept, but I have this itchy feeling if this would really work. Part of it probably because I am still having doubt about my understanding of how context, channel, errgroup are working under the hood. I have a few questions now.

Is there any fault in the new code?
Compared to previous approach and this, which one is overall better and should be recommended over another?
Can I update the new code to make it better? Or any better graceful shutdown approach?


The new function will work, but what makes it "better"? Do consider what happens if srv.ListenAndServe() returns an error (i.e. playground). Please try to ask a single question; if you are looking for a code review then please try here.
